# Does Ultra Instinct in super saiyan god powers up the transformation, or does it simply give Goku automatic dodging skills?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Recently Goku started to use Ultra Instinct when transformed in super saiyan god.

Does Ultra Instinct in super saiyan god powers up the transformation, or does it simply give Goku automatic dodging skills?

Answer (score 1):

Ultra Instinct in  Dragon ball super is like another form from super saiyyan so the powers won't stack up.
When Goku first achieved Ultra Instinct Reiss stated that Goku's attacks are weak because he is still thinking while in Ultra Instinct.So, it doesn't matter which form he is in his powers varies according to his mind set.

Answer (score 1):

Whis said that Ultra Instinct is an ability only the gods are capable of learning and that Goku is now getting a grasp of how to use it and that he is thinking of his moves instead of actually doing it instantly. Ultra Instinct is not a dodge ability, it enable the user to instantly attack, evade or defend without thought in the most perfect way possible. It's not a power up in the sense that it makes the user stronger, but it allows them to react perfectly in any senario. And no, it does not stack with the Super Saiyan God mode.